# Android json response in array

Tags: java, android

The following code shows only the first record. Can anyone correct my mistake.

Using this try i established connection with php

```
try{    
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/androidphp/1/index.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevaluepairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200){
                Log.d("MyApp", "Server encountered an error");
            }

try{

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF8"));
            sb= new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line = null;

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        }
```

Using this try block i printed all values

```
try{
                jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json_data = null;
                for(int i=0; i<jArray.length(); i++){
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    outputStream.append("Id="+json_data.getString("id"));
                    outputStream.append("Name="+json_data.getString("name"));
                }
```

Comment: Id=1 Name=XXX But i have 5 record in database.

Comment: What is the length of jArray? Place System.out.println("jArray size: " + jArray.length()) before the for loop to check the number of items in it.

Comment: When your Index always is 1, the 4 following names will be overwritten.

Comment: jArray length is 5. How can i check length because System.out.println wont work in android.

Comment: "Id=1". Has every record this data?

Comment: @Gary Klasen: output is the first record so i hope its not overwriting.

Comment: It will work. It will display the message in a console log. Alternatively you can use Log.i("JSON Array", String.valueOf(jArray.length()) )

Comment: @Gary Klasen: json object showing correct number of records.

Comment: Maybe you forgot outputStream.flush()?

Comment: I checked with logcat it shows like **[{"id":"1","name":"xxx"}][{"id":"1","name":"xxx"},{"id":"2","name":"yyy"}]**

Comment: What shows like this? The string you posted is no correct JSON. It looks like two concatenated json array strings.

Comment: post your php code here also

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not totally clear, but:

Probably the structure you want to output doesnt fit the given structure.

Looking to this: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html you can convert any JSON-Object to String with .toString()-method, to debug.

Alternatively you can actively step through your code with debugging, to find the gap.

Refering to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON it seems, that the structure you want to read, which is stored in "result" should look similar to this:

[
  {
   "id": "a",
   "name": "b"
  },
  {
   "id": "a",
   "name": "b"
  }
]

Actually reading JSON can be pragmatically done like trial & error: debug step by step and check in Eclipse' "expressions"-tab for example, which command leads to which result :)